# The '0' key is not echoed back in ZSH

Tags: zsh, keyboard, opensuse

I have just noticed a weird issue with my OpenSUSE Tumbleweed installation.

Whenever I try to type a <kbd>0</kbd> (zero) at the console prompt, it doesn't seem to be recognized.

If I launch a program from the prompt, the program recognizes the <kbd>0</kbd> key, but `zsh` itself doesn't seem to recognize it.

It's not a hardware problem since other applications recognize the key and `zsh` recognizes <kbd>)</kbd>, which is <kbd>0</kbd> with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key held down.

This installation of OpenSUSE Tumbleweed is not running in a VM, it is running on my HP laptop.

Comment: Try searching for 0 in `bind -p`.

Comment: I get "bind: command not found".

Comment: Oh sorry, `bind` is bash. :-( Use `bindkey` instead.

Comment: In the output I see `"0" overwrite-mode`.

Comment: I think I see how this happened.  My .zshrc file has the command `zkbd`.  When I was pressing the keys as requested, I pressed the Insert key in the numeric keypad without realizing that NumLock was on.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this happened because while responding to the prompts from the `zkbd` command I had pressed the Insert key in my numeric keypad without realizing that NumLock was on.